# Construct xpath kind of key value pairs map from Java object

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

By using jackson mapper, we can convert Java object to nested map with the following code.

```
ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
// some converter options
Map<String, ?> entries = MAPPER.convertValue(entity, new TypeReference<Map<String, ?>>() {});
```

But, this creates nested map, when the object is a wrapped by multiple classes.

Is there any possibility to use jackson mapper or any other framework to generate a flat map structure with parent name prefixed keys (like xpath) like below example:

### Wrapper class

```
class Car {
    numOfTypes  : int
    tyre        : List<Tyre>
    numOfSeats  : int
    seat        : Seat
}
```

### Innrer classes

```
class Tyre {
    make : String
    width : int
    profile: int
    rim : int
    speed : int
}

class Seat {
    type : String
}
```

### Flat keys Map

```
{
    "car/numOfTypes" : 4,
    "car/tyre[0]" : "",
    "car/tyre[0]/make" : "mrf"
    "car/tyre[0]/width" : "205",
    "car/tyre[0]/width" : "60",
    "car/tyre[0]/rim" : "16",
    "car/tyre[0]/speed" : "91",
    "car/tyre[1]" : "",
    "car/tyre[1]/make" : "mrf"
    "car/tyre[1]/width" : "205",
    "car/tyre[1]/width" : "60",
    "car/tyre[1]/rim" : "16",
    "car/tyre[1]/speed" : "91",
    "car/tyre[2]" : "",
    "car/tyre[2]/make" : "mrf"
    "car/tyre[2]/width" : "205",
    "car/tyre[2]/width" : "60",
    "car/tyre[2]/rim" : "16",
    "car/tyre[2]/speed" : "91",
    "car/tyre[3]" : "",
    "car/tyre[3]/make" : "mrf"
    "car/tyre[3]/width" : "205",
    "car/tyre[3]/width" : "60",
    "car/tyre[3]/rim" : "16",
    "car/tyre[3]/speed" : "91",
    "car/numOfSeats" : 2,
    "car/seat[0]" : "",
    "car/seat[0]/type" : "driver",
    "car/seat[1]" : "",
    "car/seat[1]/type" : "passinger",
}
```

We can use reflection achieve this, but loosing some of the features of Jackson framework like

1. `@JsonProperty` annotation, when the field name is differ from key name.
2. Foramtter if any applied to convert Object to string etc.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: We need to build fixed width string from Java object based on the mainframes copybook definition. We found cb2java library, which takes xml data file and constructs xpath key value pairs map and then applies copybook schema to get fixed width file. We can do Java object to xml conversion and use the library AS-IS, but can improve performance, if it's possible to convert Java object to xpath key value pair map.

Comment: I was going to say - try JsonPath. But now, I am not even sure.